# Does QGIS have a functionality similar to Flicker in Erdas Imagine?

Tags: qgis, erdas-imagine

I am trying to replace an Erdas Imagine workflow with QGIS and I have got most of it working but can't find a solution for fliker. We have it set to turn an image on and off every few seconds to visually see changes. Can this be done in QGIS? The swipe plugin is useful but not really what we want for this use case.

If there is no tool, is it possible in python... give it the name of the layer to turn on/off every X seconds?

ERDAS
[image]

[image]

QGIS
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I ended up creating a script to do this.

This asks which layer to toggle on/off, then the number of seconds to flicker and adds a pause button to the top left.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Hope it helps.

---

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QInputDialog, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QDockWidget
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QTimer
from qgis.utils import iface

timer = QTimer()
selected_layer = None
toggle_interval = 3000  # Default interval in milliseconds

# Create the dock widget to hold the control buttons
dock_widget = QDockWidget("Layer Flicker Controls", iface.mainWindow())
dock_widget.setObjectName("LayerFlickerControls")
control_widget = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout(control_widget)

# Initialize the flicker and stop buttons
flicker_button = QPushButton("Pause Flicker")
stop_button = QPushButton("Stop Flicker")

def list_layers_and_select():
    global selected_layer, toggle_interval
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    layers = list(project.mapLayers().values())
    layer_names = [layer.name() for layer in layers]
    
    layer_item, ok = QInputDialog.getItem(None, "Select Layer", "Choose a layer to flicker:", layer_names, 0, False)
    
    if ok and layer_item:
        selected_layer = next((layer for layer in layers if layer.name() == layer_item), None)
        if selected_layer:
            # Ask for the flicker interval
            seconds, ok = QInputDialog.getInt(None, "Flicker Interval", "Enter flicker interval in seconds:", 3, 1, 3600, 1)
            if ok:
                toggle_interval = seconds * 1000  # Convert seconds to milliseconds
                setup_controls()

def toggle_layer_visibility():
    layer_node = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(selected_layer.id())
    layer_node.setItemVisibilityChecked(not layer_node.isVisible())

def setup_controls():
    flicker_button.clicked.connect(toggle_flickering)
    stop_button.clicked.connect(stop_flickering)

    layout.addWidget(flicker_button)
    layout.addWidget(stop_button)
    control_widget.setLayout(layout)

    dock_widget.setWidget(control_widget)
    iface.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, dock_widget)
    start_flickering()

def toggle_flickering():
    if timer.isActive():
        timer.stop()
        flicker_button.setText("Restart Flicker")
    else:
        start_flickering()

def start_flickering():
    timer.timeout.connect(toggle_layer_visibility)
    timer.start(toggle_interval)
    flicker_button.setText("Pause Flicker")

def stop_flickering():
    timer.stop()
    timer.disconnect()
    dock_widget.close()

list_layers_and_select()
```